# Checking for null in if statement isn't working in java

Tags: java, android, if-statement, null, arrays

Here is my if statement:

```
for(int i=0;i<SharedPrefsData.subscribers.length; i++){//loop through subscribers array
        if(SharedPrefsData.subscribers[i] == null ){//if string at index i is null
            SharedPrefsData.subscribers[i] = "";//make it empty string instead of null
        }

    }
```

I want it to loop through an array of strings and check if each element is `null`. My array is:

```
[name_1, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

and yet it never enters the then part of my if statement. If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** My code that sets the array:

```
public static String[] getPrefs(){
    String[] ToReturn;
    String tempString = settings.getString("123", "0");
    if(tempString == "0"){
        //show some type of error
        ToReturn = null;
    } else {
        ToReturn = tempString.split("@,#");
    }
    return ToReturn;


}
```

And this is the statement that calls the method:

```
SharedPrefsData.setSubscribers(SharedPrefsData.getPrefs());
```

`settings` is a field in the same class of type `SharedPreferences`

Comment: Have you tried printing out the value of `SharedPrefsData.subscribers[i]` ?

Comment: Tested your code with `String[] subscribers = {"test", null, null, null};` and it goes into the if fine. Check the values of your array.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I am using eclipse so I just added a bunch of breakpoints and roll over variable to check value

Comment: if you try to print SharedPrefsData.subscribers.length, what value do you get?

Comment: I have tested your code and it works fine.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I get `15`.

Comment: provide a little bit more code. I think the problem is at another place...

Comment: Have you taken the time to check what your array actually contains? Does it contains `null` or actually a `String` that is `"null"`?

Comment: I think that it is the string `"null"`, but then shouldn't `SharedPrefsData.subscribers.equals("null")` work. It isn't

Comment: @user2297366 Can you show use the part where you have defined `subscribers` array. Its a wild guess but that could be the problem.

Comment: Since you use Eclipse, inspecting (ctrl+shift+i) the array while stopped at the loop while debugging or using the variables view, you should be able to tell exactly what is within your array. From there, you should be able to fix your condition accordingly.

Comment: @Smit it gets it from shared preferences. See my edit for code.

Comment: @user2297366 `if(tempString == "0"){` here what are you comparing a number or String? If its a string then better use `String#equals()` instead of `==` as suggested by @booleanCube Answer. And If you already want empty string later then why are you inserting `null` in `getPrefs()`

Comment: It seems strange that String.split would return null values.  Judging from your code I would think that either the Array itself is null, or there are no null values in the string.

Comment: @Brinnis My code saved it into sharedPreferences like this: `name_1@,#@,#@,#@,#@,#@,#@,#@,#@,#@,#@,#@,#@,#@,#@,#`

Comment: @user2297366 So, `settings.getString("123", "0")` returns `name_1@,#@,#@,#@,#@,#@,#@,#@,#@,#@,#@,#@,#@,#@,#@,#` correct? If that is the case try printing out the size of the Array `ToReturn` before returning it in `getPrefs()`.

Comment: @Brinnis It seems as though the `getPref()` method isn't being called correctly because it isn't going to it.

Comment: @user2297366 You need to post more of the code if you want further help, based on the code provided `getPrefs()` should return an array of length 1 containing `[name_1]`.  As I said before `String.Split` will never return a `null` value or a value in an array of an empty string or null.

Comment: @Brinnis It is calling the method ok, the breakpoints just aren't working. Anyways, `ToReturn.length = 15`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33220/discussion-between-brinnis-and-user2297366)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be in the source of data

SharedPrefsData.subscribers array might have 'null' string instead of null.
Just try

```
if(SharedPrefsData.subscribers[i] == null ||  SharedPrefsData.subscribers[i].equals("null"))
```

Again, the issue might be with the source and if the issue is resolved by above statement, you need to look at source and make sure it is not returning 'null' string in place of null object

Comment: Not entering the if-statement.

Comment: or maybe "Null"? :-) then try equalsIgnoreCase